# Win Group Overlap: Authenticated Users and System

Tags: windows, groups

I'm seeing some weird behaviour with a few of my ACEs at the minute, particularly when denying  the `Authenticated Users` instead of the usual `Domain\Domain Users`. As a consequence of this, I can only fix my problem by *allowing* the `SYSTEM` group at a lower level.

It seems Authenticated Users is blocking something that my application needs within SYSTEM.

Where do Authenticated Users and SYSTEM overlap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SYSTEM account is a member of the Authenticated Users group on the local machine. It is not a member of the Domain Users group (because it's not a domain account).

Why can't you use Domain Users to get the behaviour that you want?